# Referencing another field in cellRenderer

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am using `AG-Grid`. I have bunch of fields in `columnDefs` and a `cellRenderer` for one of the fields. I want to `refer to another field` in the `cellRenderer`. How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell renderer params property has the type `ICellRendererParams`, which you can read about in the [AG-Grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#reference-ICellRendererParams). The cell renderer params get automatically passed as a prop `params` to the cell renderer component.

The `ICellRendererParams` property `data` contains the data for the entire row, which you can use to reference your required field:

```js
const props = defineProps({
  params: {
    type: Object as PropType<ICellRendererParams>,
    required: true,
  },
});

// access the field with: props.params.data["theRequiredField"];
```